# How do that gridview table will not redownload when user push update button?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When user push update button DataBound event starting. How to lock this event? It's take much time to wait when gridview enumerates every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not `DataBind` your `GridView` on postbacks. So just wrap it in a `!IsPostBack`:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    { 
        DataBindGridView();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it. GridView has some dropdownlist which filled from db. I try lock gridview databound without locking dropdownlist bound event

Comment: @user1848942: In general: you cannot _lock_ events(whatever this means). An event is something that already happened. So you should avoid databinding if you don't want to trigger a databound event. **You should also not databind dropdownlists in a gridview from the gridview's databound event but from it's `RowDataBound` event**.

Comment: Data in gridview doesn't bound when i click on update button, but i don't know what heppend. It take much time to starting edit row. I put points every where in my project but just about 7 seconds something is done without stoping in points.